# PLPGSQL how to get query plan into table, using dynamic query execute in anonymous code block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've got Postgres 11 version. How can I put explain text while executing dynamic query in temp table?
Here is example of code, which shows only one row

```
do $$
DECLARE reca text default 'EXPLAIN select count(*) from fg.vw_metrics';
DECLARE explanation text;
BEGIN
EXECUTE reca into explanation;
create temp table aaa as select explanation;
end;
$$;
 
select * from aaa;
```

I get only the fisrt row though "Aggregate  (cost=564.45..564.46 rows=1 width=8)"

I guess I need record type here or LOOP. But I cant manage to get
output in table like:

```
Aggregate  (cost=564.45..564.46 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Seq Scan on t_metrics_dynamic  (cost=0.29..562.70 rows=140 width=1507)
        Filter: (ARRAY[(dir_id)::text, 'null'::text] && $1)
        CTE cte_rls
          ->  Function Scan on get_direction_rls  (cost=0.26..0.27 rows=1 width=32)
        InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
          ->  CTE Scan on cte_rls  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
```

The thing is that I need to use only anonymous code block. I cant create functions

Comment: You may want to use [`FORMAT JSON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) if you want to further process the `EXPLAIN` output

Comment: Yeah, that works. Maybe you know how to make that code work with text format also?

Comment: I don't know that, which is why I only wrote a comment not an answer

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks. Your solution also works!

Answer (score 0):

Manage to get it work.

```
do $$
DECLARE reca text default 'explain select count(*) from prod.sell_movement_partition';
DECLARE explanation record;
BEGIN
create temp table aaa (rrr text);
for explanation in EXECUTE reca loop
 insert into aaa (rrr) select explanation; end loop;
end;
$$;
```

or second variant with json format

```
do $$
DECLARE reca text default 'explain (format json) SELECT (*)
    FROM prod.sell_movement_partition limit 10';
DECLARE explanation jsonb;
BEGIN
EXECUTE reca into explanation;
create temp table aaa as select explanation;
end;
$$;
```